# Búsqueda por GET ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Tengo una tabla con un listado de trabajadores y necesito que al darle clic en `Ver familiares` aparezcan solo los familiares de ese trabajador estoy llevando en la URL el `cod_colaborador`:

Ejemplo:

> http://localhost:50210/familiares/Index/1212

El `cod_colaborador` es `1212`, lo estoy llevando mediante URL, necesito que en el `Index` de los familiares me filtre automáticamente por el `cod_colaborador` que envío por URL.

Mi `Controller` es este:

```
private sioldmutualEntities db = new sioldmutualEntities();

// GET: familiares
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.tb_familiares.ToList());
}
```

Mi `View` es esta:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplicationSIOldMutual.SI.tb_familiares>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nombres)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.documento_identidad)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fecha_nacimiento)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sexo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.parentesco)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.celular)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.telefono)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cod_colaborador)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombres)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.documento_identidad)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fecha_nacimiento)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sexo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.parentesco)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.celular)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.telefono)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cod_colaborador)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id_familiar }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id_familiar }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id_familiar })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: ¿Ya viste la respuesta de @Leandro http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/58651/822 ?

Comment: si pero no me funciono amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si deseas listar los familiares que corresponden a un colaborador, tienes que envíar y recibir el `Id` del colaborador a listar y luego, filtrar condicionando a ese `Id`:

```
public ActionResult Index(int Id)
{
    return View(db.tb_familiares.Where(t => t.cod_colaborador == Id).ToList());
}
```

Con esto, en el `Index` solo estarías mostrando la información de los familiares que corresponde a cada colaborador.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias implementar

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    //aqui filtras los datos con el id
    return View();
}
```

En este caso se usa el default routing, en el cual mapea el valor con el id que envies en la url

Ahora bien si quieres definir el parametro distintos debes cambiar el routing, la forma mas simple es usando el atributo [Route]

```
[Route("Home/Index/{codcolaborador}")]
public ActionResult Index(int codcolaborador)
{
    //aqui filtras los datos con el id
    return View();
}
```

Siempre esta la posibilidad de definir un nuevo routing en el `RouteConfig` que inicializa en el start de sitio

[Routing in MVC](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc)