# Problema DataAnnotation DataType para Fecha

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un problema con el DataAnnotation DataType Date, en mi vista se visualiza perfectamente la fecha tal como lo puse en el DataFormatString, pero en el momento en el que le doy editar, me aparece como si no hubiera especificado una fecha antes o no estuviera almacenada en la base de datos, dejo muestras.

Como se ve en la vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve cuando le doy Editar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
[Display(Name = "Fecha de Ingreso")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime fecha_ingreso { get; set; }
```

Codigo de la vista:

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fecha_ingreso)
    </td>
//Vista del Edit
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha_ingreso, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_ingreso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_ingreso, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione,

Reemplazar esto:

```
[Display(Name = "Fecha de Ingreso")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime fecha_ingreso { get; set; }
```

Por esto:

```
[Display(Name = "Fecha de Ingreso")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime fecha_ingreso { get; set; }
```

**Explicación:**

En HTML5 o HTML los input de tipo Date en su valué debe tener la siguiente estructura yyyy-MM-dd o Año-Mes-Dia, deje el ApplyFormatInEditMode en True debido a que como es una columna cuyo tipo de dato es DateTime contiene valores como la hora y por ende puede generar conflicto, por eso utilice el DataFormatString para darle el formato a la fecha eliminando la hora el minuto y el segundo y la habilite para que en el Edit me recupere el formato establecido.

Comment: en qué se diferencia de la respuesta http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/60136/822 ?

Comment: los ''/'' por los "-", tambien que no se tiene que cambiar el EditorFor, y por ultimo que te aparece el input tipo date.

Comment: gracias :D ese detalle del guión por el slash no me había dado cuenta, por otro lado, en el cambiar el EditorFor fue en caso de "Y si todavía te da lata". Sigue con todo el power 2.0 bro! éxitos :D

Comment: vale, aun asi muy util tu respuesta, si por favor me ayudas con este problema http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58605/busqueda-por-get-asp-net-mvc5?noredirect=1#comment108380_58605 gracias

Comment: claro, tan pronto como me de el tiempo de formular una respuesta, mientras tanto ¿Ya viste el workshop que hice?

Comment: si, he estado mirando el video, solo que pues lo veo por ratos y por partes ya que me encuentro en desarrollo

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
```

Por:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
```

Y si todavía te da lata, en la vista:

Reemplaza:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_ingreso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Por

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.fecha_ingreso, "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")
```

**TextBoxFor**: Proporcionará como elemento html de entrada de texto correspondiente a la expresión especificada. En una palabra simple, siempre renderizará como un cuadro de texto de entrada independientemente del tipo de datos de la propiedad que se está viniendo a enlazar con el control.

**EditorFor**: Este control realiza el marcado HTML basado en el tipo de datos de la propiedad. Por ejemplo: Supongamos que hay una propiedad booleana en el modelo. Para mostrar esta propiedad en la vista como una casilla de verificación, podemos usar CheckBoxFor o EditorFor. Ambos generarán el mismo marcado.

**¿Cuál es la ventaja de usar EditorFor?**

Como sabemos, dependiendo del tipo de datos de la propiedad genera el marcado html. Así que supongamos mañana si cambiamos el tipo de datos de la propiedad en el modelo, no hay necesidad de cambiar nada en la vista. El control EditorFor cambiará el marcado html automáticamente.

En otras palabras:

`Html.TextboxFor` siempre renderizará un textbox `<input type="text" ...`

Comment: No funciona, ya lo intente de esa manera

Comment: respuesta actualizada

Comment: Amigo, por favor a tu respuesta con el textboxfor podrias agregarle los atributos de tipo de dato Date, para que el html5 me proporcione el editor de fecha y tambien por favor agregarle la clase form-control, pasa que soy bastante nuevo y quiero ver como se hace, gracias

Comment: en ese caso, revisa este workshop que hice hace un tiempo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY :D

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de esta manera me funcionó perfecto:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = 
true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
```

Y no tuve que cambiar el `EditorFor`.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

amigo te recomiendo que uses ajax toolkit.

**podrias usar asi :**

```
     <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>


    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFinicio" class="form-control" Width="104px" runat="server" required></asp:TextBox>  
           <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" PopupButtonID="txtFinicio" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFinicio" Format="yyyy/MM/dd"> </cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

**Antes del HTML poner este codigo :**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

aqui te dejo el link donde podras descargar ajax :

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Install-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-in-Visual-Studio-ToolBox.aspx

Comment: brother, lo que mencionas es con ASP.net WebForms, aquí el amigo @ByGroXD anda con ASP.net MVC :D gracias por la intención :D